# Object not changing when sent to method in java?

Tags: java, object

the object i create in the main and pass to my `setValue` method isn't changing the value of the object in main. i thought objects were passed by reference and only primitive data types were passed by value. is this wrong? or is it another problem in my code

the idea is that the object array is sent to the method `setValue`.

a `temporaryObject` is created and assigned the values the user enters.

then both the temporary object and the object array are sent to another method (`findPlace`) to find the proper location in the array for it to be (greatest in `postion` 0 and lowest in the last`position`).

then it returns the location as an integer called place to setValueMethod.

then it sends the object array and `temporaryobject` to the add one method

the `addOne` method goes the the `Location` to insert (place variable) and moves every `position` down one `position` and adds the temporary object into the correct `position`.

```
public static int addOne(Footballer[] theArray, int place, Footballer theObject, int noOfValues)
        {
            int step;

            if (noOfValues == 0)
                {
                    theArray[0] = theObject;
                    noOfValues ++;  
                }
            else
                {                   
                    for (step = noOfValues - 1 ; step >= place; step --)
                        {
                            theArray[step + 1] = theArray[step] ;                       
                        }
                    theArray[place] = theObject;
                }

            return noOfValues;
        } // addOne()

    public static int findPlace(Footballer[] theArray, String theName, int noOfValues)
        {
            int step; 
            int place;

            step = 0 ;
            while ((step < noOfValues) && (theName.compareTo(theArray[step].getName()) > 0))
            {
                step ++;
            }

            place = step ;   // Finds the correct location of place 

            return place;

        } // findPlace()

    // initialises the value of the number of players
    public static int howManyPlayer()
        {
            int NUMOFPLAYERS;
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter the number of players\t\t:\t");
            NUMOFPLAYERS = num.nextInt();

            return NUMOFPLAYERS;
        }// howManyPlayer()

    public static void print(Footballer[] allPlayers, int amntOfPlayers)
        {
            // print attributes of all players to screen
            for(int i = 0; i < amntOfPlayers; i++)
                {
                    String printableAttributes;

                    printableAttributes = allPlayers[i].toString();

                    System.out.println(printableAttributes);
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                }
        } // print()

        // initialises the values of all of the players int the array
    public static Footballer[] setValue(Footballer[] playerArr, int NUMOFPLAYERS)
        {
            Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
            Footballer tempPlayer;
            String curName; // current name
            int curGoals; // current number of goals
            int curPoints; // current number of points
            int noOfElements = NUMOFPLAYERS;
            int place;

            for(int i = 0; i < NUMOFPLAYERS; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Player " + (i+1));
                    System.out.print("Enter a name\t\t\t\t:\t");
                    curName = str.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter how many goals they scored\t:\t");
                    curGoals = num.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Enter how many points they scored\t:\t");
                    curPoints = num.nextInt();

                    tempPlayer = new Footballer(curName, curGoals, curPoints);

                    System.out.println(tempPlayer.getName());
                    System.out.println(tempPlayer.getGoals());
                    System.out.println(tempPlayer.getPoints());

                    place = findPlace(playerArr, curName, noOfElements);
                    noOfElements = addOne(playerArr, place, tempPlayer, noOfElements);

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                }// for

            return playerArr;
        } // setValue()

    // the init metod bellow it meant to initalise every postion of to 
    //this initialisation method was only added to stop the Exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-NullPointerException
    public static Footballer[] initArr(Footballer[] theArray, int noOfElements)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < noOfElements+1; i++)
                {   
                    theArray[i] = new Footballer("", 0, 0);
                }// for
            return theArray;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            // declarations
            Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
            final int NUMOFPLAYERS;
            Footballer footballers[]; 
            String curName; // current name
            int curNumOfGoals; // current number of goals
            int curNumOfPoints; // current number of points

            // initialisations
            NUMOFPLAYERS = howManyPlayer();
            footballers = new Footballer[NUMOFPLAYERS+1]; 

            footballers = initArr(footballers, NUMOFPLAYERS);
            setValue(footballers, NUMOFPLAYERS); // sets values of footballers[] in order

            print(footballers, NUMOFPLAYERS); // print all player attributes
        }
```

if you want me to add the `Footballer` class i will but essentially it is this.

mutuators are:

1. `setName` to set the objects name variable
2. `setGoals` to set the number of goals scored
3. `setPoints` to set the number of points scored

selectors:

1. `getName`    returns the name set for the object
2. `getGoals`   returns the number of goals that the object has scored
3. `getPoints` returns the number of points that the object has scored

other methods:

1. `toString`   returns string with all of the objects attribute values
2. `totalPoints` sets `totalNumOfPoints = pointsScored + (goalsScored*3)` and `returns totalNumOfPoints`.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: when i call the print method at the end to print out the contents of the `footballers` object array, it prints out the initialised values. It was not changed when i gave it to the my other methods.

Comment: "i thought objects were passed by reference and only primitive data types were passed by value. is this wrong?" Yes. The difference between primitives and objects, is that primitives don't have methods, and therefore don't have mutators that could affect their content. Everything else works the same.

Comment: As I see it, you create an array with some `new Footballer("", 0, 0)`. Then you don't update them, but if at all replace the existing ones

Comment: Your program is buggy and I recommend you learn how to use the debugger, all the players you create will be inserted at the last place in the array and thus overwrite the previous object. So if you add 10 players all will be added at `playerArr[9]`. Fix the `addOne` method

Comment: @Joakim Danielson     Okay thanks i will!

Comment: talking about "selectors", "mutators" and "other methods", who would think of `static`???